# не изменяется state

Tags: reactjs, context, setstate

State не изменяется, приходит undefined

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import './App.scss';
import Header from './components/header/Header';
import Main from './components/Main/Main';
import Footer from './components/footer/Footer';
import {Context} from './contex';
import {API_KEY, API_BASE_URL} from '../src/apis/config';

function App() {

  const [ state, setState ] = useState(
    {
      city: undefined,
      country: undefined,
      img: undefined,
      temp: undefined,
      feel: undefined,
      descr: undefined,
      humidity: undefined,
      pressure: undefined,
      visibility: undefined,
      error: undefined
    }
  );

const getWeather = async (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  const city = e.target.elements.city.value;


  const apiUrl = await fetch(`${API_BASE_URL}/weather?q=${city}&appid=${API_KEY}&units=metric`);
  const data = await apiUrl.json();


setState({...state}, 
  {
      city: data.name,
      country: data.sys.country,
      img: `http://openweathermap.org/img/w/${data.weather[0].icon}.png`,
      temp: data.main.temp,
      feel: data.main.feels_like,
      descr: data.weather.description,
      humidity: data.main.humidity,
      pressure: data.main.pressure,
      visibility: data.visibility,
      error: ""
});
}
  return (
    <Context.Provider value={{
      getWeather,
      state
    }}>
        <div>
          <Header />
          <Main />
          <Footer />
        </div>
    </Context.Provider>

  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нужно передать новое значение стейта в функцию `setState`:

```
setState({
  city: data.name,
  country: data.sys.country,
  img: `http://openweathermap.org/img/w/${data.weather[0].icon}.png`,
  temp: data.main.temp,
  feel: data.main.feels_like,
  descr: data.weather.description,
  humidity: data.main.humidity,
  pressure: data.main.pressure,
  visibility: data.visibility,
  error: ""
});
```